# Class not found exception - Making a Helper on Kohana 3.1

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

got a fresh install of Kohana 3.1. Trying to make my own helpers. I have created a helper in the application/classes/helpers/ directory. I have called the file javascript.php, the class is called Helper_Javascript and has a static function that just returns "alert('sometext')" here it is

```
class Helper_Javascript {
    public static function alert($message)
    {
        return "alert('$message');\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is in my view or controller when I try to use the helper i just kepp getting the Class not found exception. I have tried to call it via `<?php echo Helper_Javascript::alert('asdf');?>` but get:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Helper_Javascript' not found.
```

Please help, I have tried to read the docs for this at                 http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2010/03/26/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-7/ but it doesnt work.

You can see my view here: http://nabilboag.dyndns.org/simplysweet/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "_" in the class name is used to represent the directory structure. You have the rename the directory "helpers" into "helper": `application/classes/helper/`