# Helper class in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana, helper

I would like to create my custom helper class, but I always get `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'media' not found` when I call `print media::alert();`.

This is my class:

```
class media_Core {
    public static function alert() {
        return "adsfasffasdsafd";
    }
}
```

Directory structure looks like this `application/helpers/media.php`. I also tried to follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524119/class-not-found-exception-making-a-helper-on-kohana-3-1), but still can't get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Kohana 3.3 conventions](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions) the class mappings behave like this:

- `media_Core` maps to `application/classes/media/Core.php`
- `Helpers_Media` maps to `application/classes/Helpers/Media.php`

The conventions page also describes style guidelines on naming your classes.

If you wish to call `media::alert()`, your class must be named `media` and be found in `application/classes/media.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The name should be Helpers_Media, so that Kohana can find your class in helpers/ directory 
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/conventions

Comment: The helpers directory is ignored, unless it's a subdir of `classes`. Also the docs link is for the wrong version ;)